# Gather information from different folder levels in CMake

Tags: cmake

I have a project with different, configurable dependencies:

```
IF(HAVE_LIBA)
  ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(something)
ENDIF()

IF(HAVE_LIBB)
  ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(somethingElse)
ENDIF()
```

I would like to have a central list of libraries, include paths and installation paths of the libraries that finally have been built with a certain configuration.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
SET(MYPROJECT_LIBS "")
```

something/CMakeLists.txt:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(somethingLib ...)
# Howto append somethingLib to MYPROJECT_LIBS
```

SET(... PARENT_SCOPE) [CMake >= 2.6] would be one way to go, however, I have several levels of folders and parent scope only modifies the variable of one level above.

Caching MYPROJECT_LIBS also had no effect.

Any other (maybe general) suggestions on how to populate these lists?

Comment: What do you mean by "Caching MYPROJECT_LIBS also had no effect"?

Comment: @Peter I tried SET(var ".." CACHE INTERNAL "") in the sub-directories which did not modify var for top-level, but what was probably a scope mistake, because I had var also instantiated on local scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Populate a global property instead.

```
set_property(GLOBAL APPEND PROPERTY THE_LIBS_PROP liba)
```

Read:

```
get_property(THE_LIBS GLOBAL PROPERTY THE_LIBS_PROP)
message("The libs: ${THE_LIBS}")
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much. Any suggestions on a different design?

Comment: Without knowing what you're using the content for, it's impossible to recommend anything different.